# Sort one array based on another array using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays

1. MRP  `[60 80 82 50 80 80 ]`
2. Brand `[ A B  C  D  E   F ]`

I need to get top two brands based on MRP. highest two in MRP is 82 ,80 but 80 is 3 times repeated so i need all repeated values as well to get top two brands. i.e i need to display `[C B E F]`

For that i sorted  MRP in descending order.Now MRP after sorting become `[ 82 80 80 60 50 ]`

Now i need to sort Brand Array based on Sorted MRP.Can some one help in this sorting using javascript .

Comment: Any attempts on your own so far? Is this Java or JavaScript?

Comment: @ZiNNED I only sorted the first array ie MRP bt not the brands.but now i got the solution shared by Nishanthi Grashia in the subsequent post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below code

```
var A = [60, 80, 82, 50, 80, 80];
var B = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

var all = [];

for (var i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
    all.push({ 'A': A[i], 'B': B[i] });
}

all.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.A - a.A;
});

A = [];
B = [];

for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
   A.push(all[i].A);
   B.push(all[i].B);
}    

alert(A);
alert( B);
```

Comment: Happy to help! Please also upvote and accept as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash/underscore:

```
var A = [60, 80, 82, 50, 80, 80];
var B = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

var result = _.unzip(_.sortBy(_.zip(A, B), '-0'));

var A_sorted = result[0]; // [82, 80, 80, 80, 60, 50]
var B_sorted = result[1]; // ["c", "b", "e", "f", "a", "d"]]
```